# Как получить обновления(новые) посты из телеграмм группы с помощью бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Здравствуйте, есть уже немного написанный код для бота, но то, что написано не связано с самим вопросом.
Всё что я хотел узнать\спросить, дак это - можно ли получать обновления, новые посты(а с ними и текст этих постов естественно) из каналов телеграмм с помощью бота? Или можно это как-то осуществить с помощью бота, который будет получать обновления от юзера, который уже в канале телеграмм?
Просто как не искал, не мог найти инфы по этому поводу.
Посмотрел telegram api, некоторые форумы, загуглил и тд, но максимум, что нашёл, дак это то, что нужно включить privacy mode и сделал бота allowed для groups
Надеюсь немного поняли меня. Если нет, то с радостью поясню ещё точнее =)

Заранее благодарю за какой-либо ответ)

Comment: Есть api телеграм для юзера (не для бота), погуглите MadelineProto. Если точнее, то автор позиционирует это как telegram client на php.

Comment: Еххх, php.. ну ладненько, подтянем, давно  я им не занимался, благодарю во всяком случае =)